# Verilog: Using reg As Counters For for-loops

Tags: verilog

In a module:

```
reg a, b;
integer i, j;

initial
     begin
          for (a = 0; a < 2; a = a + 1)     
               //some code
     end
```

The textbook says it would be incorrect to get rid of integers **i** and **j** and use reg **a** and **b** directly as loop counters. Hint: reg variables have a fixed size and, hence, they wrap.

What does that mean? Doesn't integer have a fixed size as well? And what's wrapping?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=integer+wrapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reg is either single bit, or multiple bit if you define it as an array. An integer, on the other hand is 32 bits. So if you have a loop, it is more convenient to use an integer variable that doesn't overflow as the loop advances.

In your example, you set `a < 2`, so with a single bit reg the loop never terminates.

Moreover integers are singed values.

Comment: integer is 32 bit in verilog, never 64. Single-bit reg will overflow and loop will never exit. You need at least 2-bit reg.